# Scrollbars showing in chrome extension default popup

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

I am developing a chrome extension with a default popup (an html file). This is the simplest example of my problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html >
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
                overflow: hidden;
                height : 600px;
                width : 800px;
            }
            body{
                margin : 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on the extension icon in the topbar the popup is displayed, as expected. However, both the x- and y-axis of the popup page have scrollbars even though the maximum allowed dimensions for chrome extension popups are 800px in width and 600px in height. This is also the dimensions I provide the html tag initially. Therefore, these scrollbars are unexpected behavior. Also, if I, in the inspection tool, disable the width and height of the html tag, and afterwards enable the width and height of the html tag, the scrollbars are gone.
I want to get rid of the scrollbars. Hope someone can help.

EDIT: the following are screenshots of the situation.

**When the popup is clicked at first**
[image]
**After disabling the width and height of the html element**
[image]
**After re-enabling the width and height of the html element**
[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of the problem?

Comment: Yes, one moment

Comment: I don't see scrollbars with your html in modern Chrome but I remember this bug was present in a much older version. Could be OS-dependent. Anyway, definitely sounds like a bug, but just to be sure, check if you have zoomed any of your extension's pages in a tab (there's a "plus" indicator in the address bar) because Chrome applies the same zoom to the popup as well.

Comment: @RHShanks92 Screenshots uploaded

Comment: @wOxxOm That's it. Solved. Thanks a lot! I had a different window as part of my extension which was zoomed.

As a follow up question. Do you know how to disable zoom on all the chrome extension webpages?

Comment: Also, I am new here on stack overflow. Should the solution to this problem be provided in the answer section? Should I provide it or how does this work?

Comment: Chrome 76 and newer ignore the zoom level of extension pages when showing the popup since https://crbug.com/957115 was fixed so it's weird you're seeing it in modern Chrome. Might be worth reporting on https://crbug.com.

Comment: @wOxxOm hmm.. could this be because I use chromium?

Comment: 99.9999% of Chrome is also Chromium. Modern Chromium doesn't have this bug here.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot :)